# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: posts_post.group_id

Tags: python, sql, django

Не могу понять в чем проблема и как ее решить
[image: ошибка]

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model() 

class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name= 'posts')
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        Group,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name = 'posts',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    ordering = ['-pub_date']
```

*views.py*

````
from .models import Post, Group


def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10]
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/index.html', context) 


def group_posts(request, slug):
    
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, slug=slug)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(group=group).order_by('-pub_date')[:10]
    context = {
        'group': group,
        'posts': posts,
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/group_list.html', context) 

def groups(request):

    template = 'posts/groups.html'
    group = Group.objects.order_by()
    title = "Все группы"
    context = {
        'groups': group,
        'title': title,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)```
````

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Ошибка в `templates/base.html`. Добавьте его в свой пост.